# Trying to make a dynamic dropdown in php from database

Tags: php

I got a little question I want to make a loop so I have a dropdown menu with the data. For example: A user has a beginning time of 12:00:00 and an end time of 14:00:00. The loop is supposed to pick out 30 min, so that you have a dropdown menu with 12:00:00, 12:30:00, 13:00:00, 13:30:00 and 14:00:00. 
I will get the following data

```
$starttime = 12:00:00
$endtime = 14:00:00
$talktime = 00:30:00
```

now I want to make a dropdown menu from it that it loops.
here is my example how I thought it would work.

```
for ($endtime = $starttime + $talktime){}
```

But as the code works I want to check the database if the data already exist. I know how to do that part only the loop I don't know.

Already thank you for the help.

Comment: That is not a for loop. That is a condition that is valid only for one value

Comment: what is your expected out put ?

Comment: There are plenty of guides / tutorials out there on how loops works, at least provide an example with the correct syntax for a loop.

Comment: Every time between like 12:00:00 - 12:30:00 - 13:00:00 - 13:30:00

Comment: do you want a loop that runs after every 30 mins?

Comment: I want to make a loop so I have a dropdown menu with the data. For example: A user has a beginning time of 12:00:00 and an end time of 14:00:00. The loop is supposed to pick out 30 min, so that you have a dropdown menu with 12:00:00, 12:30:00, 13:00:00, 13:30:00 and 14:00:00.

Comment: That's a better explanation of what you are hoping to achieve.  How about editing that into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php
$starttime = new DateTime("12:00:00");
$endtime = new DateTime("14:00:00");
?>
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
<?php
while($starttime <= $endtime)
{

    echo "<option value='".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."'>".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."</option>";

    $starttime = date_add($starttime, date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 min'));
}
echo " </select>";
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help it works all the above code is good and works. Really thanks this helps me a lot. –

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $starttime = new DateTime( '12:00:00' );
    $endtime   = new DateTime( '14:00:00' );
?>
<select>
<option></option>
<?php 
    for( $i = $starttime; $i <= $endtime; $i->modify( '+ 30 minutes' ) )
    {
?>
    <option> <?php echo $i->format( 'H:i' ); ?> </option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Each loop adds 30 minutes to the time.

Comment: Thank you all for the help it works all the above code is good and works. Really thanks this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            <?php

            $starttime  = "12:00:00";
            $endtime = "14:30:00";

            $starttime = strtotime($starttime);
            $endtime = strtotime($endtime);
            $tNow = $starttime;

            while($tNow <= $endtime){
                echo date("H:i:s",$tNow)."<br>";
              $tNow = strtotime('+30 minutes',$tNow);
            }



            ?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help it works all the above code is good and works. Really thanks this helps me a lot. –