# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::format()

Tags: php

I know that the error says that format isn't a valid code, but I used it before and it worked fine. So I hope someone knows a code to replace it with or now how to fix it.

```
require_once 'config.php';

$checker = "SELECT StartTime FROM ap21_Teachers WHERE Mentor_Class = 'I2C'";
$checker2 = "SELECT EndTime FROM ap21_Teachers WHERE Mentor_Class = 'I2C'";
$checker3 = "SELECT Minutes FROM ap21_Teachers WHERE Mentor_Class = 'I2C'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $checker);
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $checker2);
$minutes = mysqli_query($mysqli, $checker3);

$starttime = new DateTime($result1);
$endtime = new DateTime($result2);

    while($starttime <= $endtime)
    {

    echo "<option value='".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."'>".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."</option>";

    $starttime = date_add($starttime, date_interval_create_from_date_string($minutes, ' min'));
    }

    echo " </select>";
```

and above I grab the vars out of the database

Comment: did you even "Google that" error? The question doesn't hold water.

Comment: i googled it but couldn't find the right answer i was hoping someone knew it.

Comment: The error says that the class `mysqli_result` does not have a method called `format()` .... that's pretty descriptive.

Comment: It's also related to your other question you posted earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/40255283/ and got an answer from it. So, what changed since?

Comment: yes and i know it doesn't now the format but i need to replace it with something but i don't know where to replace it with.

Comment: Exactly why are you treating a mysqli result object as a date string?

Comment: The problem is most likely where you've defined `$starttime` which is not something you've provided in this code.

Comment: edited the sql code with it

Comment: Why are you doing so many different SELECTs? Just do `SELECT StartTime, EndTime, Minutes ...` and check if the times are equal to something. I hope you're using MySQL's date(time) column types, because that's what they're made for and there are other functions for this. Consult the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i am using the colums and i am doing the different queries so i don't have to devide them because i didn't learn that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result` which you need to read before using:

```
require_once 'config.php';

$checker = "SELECT StartTime, EndTime, Minutes FROM ap21_Teachers WHERE Mentor_Class = 'I2C'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $checker);      //Execute query

 if (!$result) { //Result may be false if there's an error
     echo "Error getting result";
 }
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //Put first result in an array
 if (!$row) {  // $row will be false if there's no result
     echo "No data found";
 }

 //Notice how the array entry keys match the columns in the query.     
 $starttime = new DateTime($row["StartTime"]);
 $endtime = new DateTime($row["EndTime"]);         
 $minutes = $row["Minutes"];

while($starttime <= $endtime)
{

     echo "<option value='".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."'>".$starttime->format('H:i:s')."</option>";

     $starttime = date_add($starttime, date_interval_create_from_date_string($minutes, ' min'));
}

echo " </select>";
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. And thank you for the comments.